# Visual Studio - Strange Behavious in auto-complete

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Just recently my Visual Studio has started behaving incorrectly for auto complete. Take the below example:

Model. -> I get the properties of the model listed, I select one and hit enter (or tab) and the line becomes:

ModelProperty.

So the property has been dropped in BEFORE the fullstop.

This is driving me mad - any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Can you share screenshot of gif with this behavior?

Comment: Is `Model` a property of the containing class, or is it a static class?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski - added

Comment: @MatthewWatson - its just a class model that has been passed to this MVC view.

Comment: @David Whiteford, please try to delete `.vs` folder in your solution and rebuild it to check if it exits the problem.